# How can I debug C++ code called from Python on a remote machines using PyCharm?

Tags: python, c++, debugging, pycharm

How can I debug C++ code called from Python on a remote machines?

I'm using PyCharm, but its debugger doesn't seem to allow you to debug mixed code. What alternatives do I have? I know about gdb but I need some usage details.

Comment: We can start by saying that [remote debugging](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-debugging-with-product.html) is a feature of PyCharm Professional edition.

Comment: @bad_coder I have the Professional edition, it debugs normal python code, but when arrives at C code it is jumping over it.

Comment: I honestly don't have the slightest idea, I debug my code using 1 IDE per language. But this is an interesting question I'm following it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pycharm ia a python IDE, it cannot be used to debug c++ directly.
If you can use other ides, such as VSCode , the link below may help you.
https://nadiah.org/2020/03/01/example-debug-mixed-python-c-in-visual-studio-code/.

If using gdb, you can use command:

```
gdb --args python your_python_script.py
```

then you can debug as a standalone cpp executable, such as set breakpoints, run, step and so on.